IMAGENES EN HTML O CSS
Al añadir un link externo para insertar una imagen normalmente me carga la imagen en el sitio web pero con muy baja calidad, ¿hay alguna manera de subirle la calidad desde html o css?

Si la imagen original es muy pequeña, no hay nada que hacer. Si la imagen es muy grande es probable que también se vea mal. En este último caso, redimencionala a un tamaño optimizado para web. Lo más común es usar thumbnails para cargar la página y que se abra el archivo original cuando el usuario les de clic.

Prueba creando imágenes vectoriales, son la mejor opción para evitar la perdida de calidad.
